# Lede and multiwan (mwan3), all interfaces offline

Tags: networking, openwrt, embedded-linux

I've created two WAN interfaces, called `wan` and `wan2`, both show up in the `Load balancing` tab as being offline.

I can still access the internet but I want to set up multiwan to direct specific zone's outbound traffic to a specific wan interface.

This is my configuration: [Config Files](https://gist.github.com/lewisdiamond/f9880f6d4667f50411105950106f6ce5) (shared as link because it's quite lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the version of mwan3 installed did not match the version of lede running. mwan3 failed to run (only had an exit code, no output) because the binaries it need were not in the right location.

Solution, update the packages feed, install new versions, build, flash, worked.